# CodeIgniter, Call to a member function post() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i am new in CodeIgniter (v.2.1.4). I have a problem with getting post from model.

I have a contoller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        $data['main_view'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('login/include/template', $data);
    }

    public function validate(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Име', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Парола', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');

        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $this->load->model('users_model');

            if($this->users_model->validate_login($username, $password)){
                //valid user
            }
            else{
                //not vlaid user
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->index();
        }
    }
}
```

and a model:

```
class Users_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function validate_login(){
        $username = $this->input->post('user');
        $password = md5($this->input->post('pass'));

        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return TRUE;
        }
        else return FALSE; 
    }
}
```

When send via form (post) valid pair (username and password) nothing happens, but in apache2 log appears this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function where() on a non-object in /var/www/ci/application/models/users_model.php

What is wrong?

Comment: Please do not use md5 for password hashing, it's not very secure. Also always use a salt when you hash passwords. I recommend you use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php this instead.

Answer (score 3):

Add a constructor to the Login class

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: This _shouldn't_ make any difference, the parent constructor is called by default if no constructor is set in the child (overloaded).

Comment: The login class extends CI_Controller, therefore in order to inherit those methods you need to have a constructor.

Comment: Having a constructor that has a sole purpose of calling the parent constructor is pointless, you only need this if you have __additional__ code in the constructor. See: http://codepad.org/wO07H2Y5

Comment: Do you even codeigniter? He's using CI's methods, therefore he has to do it this way.

Comment: Yes, i dont know what happends

Comment: @FDL Your code proves nothing relevent to the problem here. He is using a PHP framework, not vanilla PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have database loaded? You need to load the database first.

You can either add it to /config/autoload.php to autoload database function:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Or call on demand like this:

`$this->load->database();`

More details [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)

Comment: database is loaded:$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session'); if i comment rows with post, next error is  Call to a member function where() on a non-object, the problem is in model, i think?

Comment: Could you try to load database inline like this: `$this->load->database();` just before using where() in model

Comment: The problem is not with database, another error is: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function post() on a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

Do Not Use post in model instead use this in controller like this

controller login.php

```
public function validate(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Име', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Парола', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->load->model('users_model');

        $post = $this->input->post();

        $data['username']   =   $post['username'];
        $data['password']   =   md5($post['password']);
        if($this->users_model->validate_login($data)){
            //valid user
        }else{
            //not vlaid user
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Model

```
function validate_login($where){
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE; 
}
```

This should work. Remember calling post somehow doesn't work in model. I dont exactly know they reason.